# Can I catch specific exceptions globally in a Razor Page (all handler methods) and include them in ModelState?

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'd like to allow all handler methods in a Razor Page to be wrapped by some sort of logic to handle specific exceptions that are more or less validation exceptions.

I've tried the following, but still get the developer exception page:

```
    public override async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            await next();
        }
        catch(NotImplementedException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning(ex, ex.Message);
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Oops... this isn't all done yet.");
            context.Result = Page();
        }
        catch (DomainValidationException ex)
        {
            ModelState.Include(ex.Results);
            context.Result = Page();
        }  
    }
```

The exception does not appear to bubble up from the `await next()` call and is handled in aspnetcore somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the next returns a result that needs to be inspected to get the exception and return the result.

The final implementation looks something like this:

```
public override async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
{
    var result = await next();

    if (result.Exception != null)
    {
        if (result.Exception is NotImplementedException nex)
        {
             result.ExceptionHandled = true;
            _logger.LogWarning(nex, nex.Message);
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Oops... this isn't all done yet.");
        }
        else if (result.Exception is DomainValidationException dex)
        {
            result.ExceptionHandled = true;
            ModelState.Include(dex.Results);
        }

        if (result.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            result.Result = Page();
        }
    }
}
```